# Cauchy Sequence in Measure

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of functions in $L_{1}$. Show that 
>   $\{f_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in mean if and only if 
>   $$\int_{E}f_{n}d\mu=x_{n}$$
>   is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers for every $E\in\mathscr{F}$, and 
>   $\{f_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in measure. Give an Example of a sequence which does not converge in measure, for which 
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E}f_{n}d\mu=0$$
>   for all $E$.

Comment: Please show what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First suppose that $\{f_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in mean then for  any 
>       given $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N$ then 
>       $\int|f_{n}-f_{m}|d\mu <\varepsilon,~\forall n,m\ge N$, but 
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>      |x_{n}-x_{m}|&=&\left| \int_{E} (f_{n}-f_{m})d\mu\right|\le \int_{E}|f_{n}-f_{m}|
>      d\mu \le \int|f_{n}-f_{m}|d\mu\\
>      &<&\varepsilon
>     \end{eqnarray*}
>       its proofs that $\{x_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, but as $\{f_{n}
>     \}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L_{1}$ then it is a Cauchy sequence.
>     Conversely suppose that for any fixed $E\in\mathscr{F}$ the sequence
>       $\int_{E} f_{n}d\mu = x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers and $\{f_{n}\}$ is 
>       a Cauchy sequence in measure.
>       By theorem 7.5(i) given in class, all we need to proof is that
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>        \nu_{n}(\Omega)=\int|f_{n}|d\mu\ge\nu_{n}(E)=\int_{E}|f_{n}|d\mu\ge |x_{n}|
>     \end{eqnarray*}
>       $\nu_{n}$ is equicontinuous at $\varnothing$ for all $n$, but for any $n\in
>     \mathbb{N},~f_{n}\in L_{1}$  so $|f_{n}|$ is integrable and
>       $\nu_{n}(\Omega)<\infty$. Given any sequence 
>       $\{B_{i}\}$ in $\mathscr{F}$ with $B_{i}\downarrow\varnothing$ define 
>       $f_{n}^{i}=\chi_{_{B_{i}}}|f_{n}|$ then follows that $|f_{n}^{i}|\le |f_{n}|$ by
>       the dominated convergence theorem 
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>        \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\int_{B_{i}}|f_{n}|d\mu=
>        \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{n}^{i}d\mu= 
>        \int \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}^{i}d\mu= 
>        \int 0d\mu = 0
>     \end{eqnarray*}
>       then each $\nu_{n}$ is equicontinuous at $\varnothing$